# How do I find the second most frequent value in Google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

[image]

I am using =MODE(B1:F85) to get the MODE, how do I get which is the second most frequent value after 10? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should return the second most frequent value:

`=ArrayFormula(MODE(IF((B1:F85=MODE(B1:F85)),"",B1:F85)))`

---

As an aside, I think the fact you need to use "" in the second argument, rather than omitting the argument altogether, is (in my opinion) a low-grade bug, which I will report. Nevertheless, the above formula should still work even if the behaviour was changed accordingly.

Comment: thanks, that works fine. I was thinking if I can figure out how to work out the second frequent value I will be able to find the 3 and 4th value as well. 1st mode = 10, using your formula gives me 24 and then I need to work out 3rd and 4th and thats it, just need to work out the 4 most frequent values out of all the numbers. Thanks