# How do I find the third most frequent value in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to find the third most frequent value in a google sheet. I saw how to find the second and first one, but I can't find out how to find the third and up. I need to know how to calculate the third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, and eighth places. I am working on a leaderboard system for the school I work at. 
I know this is how to find the second most frequent:

```
=ArrayFormula(MODE(IF((F1:F85=MODE(F1:F85)),"",F1:F85)))
```

and this is how to find the first:

```
=mode(F1:F65)
```

I need to find all the ones that come after that, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to find all the ones that come after that, though.

The more scalable solution that avoids nested IFs would be something along the lines of:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({F1:F85,LEN(F1:F85)},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2 > 0 group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc",0))`

This produces a table of each number and their associated frequency, sorted from most frequent to least. You can retrieve the specific value from this table using INDEX:

`=INDEX(QUERY({F1:F85,LEN(F1:F85)},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col2 > 0 group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc",0),n+1,1)`

where n is the position you require (1 = most frequent, 2 = second-most frequent, etc).

<s>Your initial</s> [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326857/how-do-i-find-the-second-most-frequent-value-in-google-sheet) was referring to a 2-dimensional range, which will be a bit more complicated, but still doable.

Comment: Is there any way to make the table go horizontally? Because that would make it a lot easier, since I have a table just like it using queries instead of that. Please help me if there is a way to make the table horizontal.

Comment: You could use the `TRANSPOSE` function to change the orientation.

Comment: @AdamL could you please explain the first parameter of `QUERY()`; what does `{F1:F85,LEN(F1:F85)}` do to the range `F1:F85`? Any reference to this will also be great!

Answer (score 1):

Given B1:B99 as our range, if A1 is most common, A2 is second most common, et cetera:

```
A1 = ArrayFormula(MODE(B1:B99))
A2 = ArrayFormula(MODE(IF((B1:B99=A1),"",B1:B99)))
A3 = ArrayFormula(MODE(IF((B1:B99=A1),"",(IF((B1:B99=A2),"",B1:B99)))))
A4 = ArrayFormula(MODE(IF((B1:B99=A1),"",(IF((B1:B99=A2),"",(IF((B1:B99=A3),"",B1:B99)))))))
```

I'm curious if anyone has a better solution though.

Comment: Thank you so much. It took a while for me to get it, but I get the solution now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is a more elegant solution to this than the other answers give.

Try using this [Google Visualization API Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en):

```
=query(A:B,"select A, count(B) group by A order by count(B) desc label count(B) 'Count' ",1)
```

This should give you 2 columns – the first gives the distinct values in your Column A, the second gives the number of occurrences for each value (sorted in descending order).

You should note that it seems that queries on single columns aren't supported, so I admit that the query is a little messy (although it should work if you just keep the B column empty).